# How to solve (or describe as a matrix equation) the following system of linear equations with no common variables, but with additional constraints?

Tags: linear-algebra

#### Semantics (for intuitive understanding)

Consider a number of individuals that must produce a certain amount of each of a number of outputs, and whose productivity for each output varies between the individuals. The goal is to produce the required amount of each output while minimizing the amount of time that each individual has to spend producing outputs.

#### Model

Denote an individual by $i \in {1, ..., n}$ and an output by $j \in {1,..., m}$. Denote the output $j$ produced by individual $i$ by $u_{ji}$, the productivity of output $j$ by individual $i$ by $\pi_{j i}$, and the time that individual $i$ spends producing output $j$ by $t_{ji}$.

We want to find the value for every time $t_{j i}$ spent on task $j$ by individual $i$, such that the total time that each individual spends producing outputs $\Sigma_j t_{j i}$ is simultaneously minimized, while enough of each output $u_j'$ is produced (specified by the below system of linear equations):

$\begin{array}{lcl} 
\pi_{1 1} t_{1 1} + \pi_{1 2} t_{1 2} + ... + \pi_{1 n} t_{1 n} &= u_1' \\
\pi_{2 1} t_{2 1} + \pi_{2 2} t_{2 2} + ... + \pi_{2 n} t_{2 n} & = u_2' \\
... \\
\pi_{m 1} t_{m 1} + \pi_{m 2} t_{m 2} + ... + \pi_{m n} t_{m n} & = u_m' \\
\end{array}$

where all $\pi_{ji}$ and $u_j'$ are known. We also have the additional constraint that an individual $i$ cannot spend more time producing outputs than the time $T$ that is passed on the clock, such that $\forall i (\Sigma_j t_{j i} \leq T)$, where $T$ is known.

#### Questions

1. How can one write the above system of linear equations as a matrix equation? Preferably in such a way as to separate the known productivity constants $\pi_{ji}$ in one matrix (say $\Pi$) from the variable times $t_{ji}$ in another matrix (say $\tau$). I'm struggling to do so, yet doing so should be instructive in how to solve it (by finding inverse matrices for example).
2. What (if any) are the solutions to the problem?
3. If (2) cannot be answered, then how many solutions (if any) are there to the problem? Statements on over- and underspecification are welcome.
4. Other thoughts or comments on the problem.